# Php for loop declare variables with two flexible numbers in their names

Tags: php

I try a for loop or any other loop (I have no idea how to do it in php) that will help me declare as many variables as the user defines. These variables are from textareas with names: answer11, answer12, answer13 (for question 1 of course), then I have answer21, answer22, answer23, answer24, etc... for as many question as user defines.

```
for($j=1; $j<$size; $j++) {

  if($_POST['question'][$j] != "")
  {
    //these can be unlimited. This is only for question1 as you can see, but how to add for more question
    $answer11 = $_POST['answer11'];
    $answer12 = $_POST['answer12'];
    $answer13 = $_POST['answer13'];

    $answer[$j] = '<input type="radio" name="ans11">'.$answer11.'<br/>';
    $answer[$j] .= '<input type="radio" name="ans12">'.$answer12.'<br/>';
    $answer[$j] .= '<input type="radio" name="ans13">'.$answer13.'<br/>';

    $print .= $j.') '.$question[$j].'<br/>'.$answer[$j].'<br/><br/>';
  }

}
```

How the loop should look like? I believe it is pretty easy but I cannot see the solution :(

Comment: You can try maybe with variables instead of numbers in the name attributes. For example answer$j$k but define for loop before.

Comment: Why individual variables?! Use arrays! It's a typical newbie trap to fall into, but you really want to use arrays here. In fact, `$_POST` already is an array!

Comment: I was also using that method up until recently, Started using arrays and it's better imo.

Comment: Yes I am rookie in php, and that's why I avoided array here. Probably shoudn't do that, I think I must figure out how to do it using arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use an array to store the answers. I'm not sure what those answers are, but you can do something like that and adapt to suit your need :

```
for($j=1; $j<$size; $j++) 
{
    if($_POST['question'][$j] != "") 
    {
        $post_answer = $_POST['answer'];

        foreach ($post_answer as $k => $ans)
        {
            $answer .= '<input type="radio" name="answer['.$k.']">'.$ans.'<br/>';
        }

        $print .= $j.') '.$question[$j].'<br/>'.$answer.'<br/><br/>';
    }
}
```